# Them vs Their in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

1. Their quitting on you is their loss.
2. Them quitting on you is their loss.

Comment: What do you think yourself? Why would one of them be wrong?

Comment: Instead of closing this question as "lacking details", I tried to find a duplicate. If it does not address your question, please [edit] your post to explain why. Please see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.